# Is there a way to edit the title of GNU GRUB2 itself (not a title of a menu entry)?

Tags: grub2, banner

I'm interested in knowing if there's a way to edit the GRUB2 boot menu to display a banner at the top.

We have several machines that boot from SAN.  I'm doing migrations and our SAN team inadvertently zoned the OS disk for the wrong machine to my server.  I let it boot and it went into contention with the production server, causing a big mess.

If there was a way I could add a banner to the top, I could see what disk was booting before the OS started to load.

Alternatively, I was thinking of adding a duplicate or null entry to the bottom of the list with a different title, I was just looking for a more professional way to do it.  Writing a script to generate custom splash screens with the servername in the background seems like a hassle.

Comment: Not easily, apparently: http://askubuntu.com/a/361185/158442